# search in words on an string and change formatting

Tags: php, search

I wan't to create a highlight tag search function via php

when I search a part of word...whole of word be colored

for example this is a sample text:

Text: British regulators say traders used private online chatrooms to coordinate their buying and selling to shift currency prices in their favor.

when I search "th" the output be like this:

Text: British regulators say traders used private online chatrooms to coordinate **their** buying and selling to shift currency prices in **their** favor.

So...I tried this code...please help me to complete it.

This is a algorithm:

```
$text= "British regulators say...";
foreach($word in $text)
{
  if( IS There "th" in $word)
   {
      $word2= '<b>'.$word.'</b>'
      replace($word with word2 and save in $text) 
   }
}
```

how can I it in php language?

Comment: strpos might help you here, if the condition is met - then wrap it in strong tags - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Any of these help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function highLightWords($string,$find)
{
   return preg_replace('/\b('.$find.'\w+)\b/', "<b>$1</b>", $string); 
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$string="British regulators say traders used private online chatrooms to coordinate their buying and selling to shift currency prices in their favor.";
$find="th";
print_r(highLightWords($string,$find));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/220357)**

**Edit after your comment:**

> ...How can I do it for middle characters? for example "line"

Very easy, just update the regex pattern accordingly

```
return preg_replace("/\b(\w*$find\w*)\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $string);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/221529)**

Comment: Thank you :) ...How can I do it for middle characters? for example "line"

Answer (score 2):

Use strpos() to find the position of the character you search for.. Then start reading from that identified position of character to till you don't find any space..

Answer (score 1):

Should be much easier:

```
$word = "th";
$text = preg_replace("/\b($word.*?)\b/", "<b>$1</b>", $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a lot of things.

First, as you know php is a server-side code, so, as long as you won't mind reload the page each time or use ajax...

The correct way i think will be using Javascript to Achieve this.

That said to explode the text you need to use another function, to be sure of what obtained:

Something like:

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
$words = explode(" ",$str);
```

Now Words var will contain the exploded string.

Now you can loop and replace (for example) and then re-construct the string and print it or do other.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the following code

```
   <?php

    $string = "British regulators say traders used private online chatrooms to coordinate their buying and selling to shift currency prices in their favor";

     $keyword = "th";
     echo highlightkeyword($string , $keyword );

    function highlightkeyword($str, $search) {
        $occurrences = substr_count(strtolower($str), strtolower($search));
        $newstring = $str;
        $match = array();

        for ($i=1;$i<$occurrences;$i++) {
            $match[$i] = stripos($str, $search, $i);
            $match[$i] = substr($str, $match[$i], strlen($search));
            $newstring = str_replace($match[$i], '[#]'.$match[$i].'[@]', strip_tags($newstring));
        }

        $newstring = str_replace('[#]', '<b>', $newstring);
        $newstring = str_replace('[@]', '</b>', $newstring);
        return $newstring;

    }

    ?>
```

Check here https://eval.in/220395

Comment: Yes O/p was correct they have displaying in `pre` tag so bold was not appearing

Comment: Thanks a lot but I want to bold the word...not a part of it.